Hangfire recurring job with NSubstitute
I need to unit test my hangifre recurring job with NSubstitute, my service class as follows, now I need to run test for it.
public class ItemService : IItemService, IJobConfigurationService
 {
     private readonly IItemRepository itemRepository;
     private readonly ISettingRepository settingRepository;
     private readonly ILogger<ItemService> logger;

     public ItemService(IItemRepository itemRepository
         ,ISettingRepository settingRepository
         ,ILogger<ItemService> logger)
     {
         this.itemRepository = itemRepository;
         this.settingRepository = settingRepository;
         this.logger = logger;
     }

     public void ConfigureJob(string cronExpression)
     {
         RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("PermanentlyDeleteItemsAsync", () =>
             PermanentlyDeleteItemsAsync(), cronExpression);
     }

     public async Task PermanentlyDeleteItemsAsync()
     {
         //some logic here
     }
 }

I tried my unit test method something like this,
[Fact]
public async Task ConfigureJob_AddsOrUpdateRecurringJobAsync()
{
    // Arrange
    var itemRepository = Substitute.For<IItemRepository>();
    var settingRepository = Substitute.For<ISettingRepository>();
    var logger = Substitute.For<ILogger<ItemService>>();
    var mockRecurringJobManager = Substitute.For<IRecurringJobManager>();

    var service = new ItemService(itemRepository, settingRepository, logger);
    string cronExpression = "0 * * * *"; // Every hour

    // Act
    service.ConfigureJob(cronExpression);

    // Assert
    mockRecurringJobManager.Received().AddOrUpdate(Arg.Any<string>(),
        () => service.PermanentlyDeleteItemsAsync(), cronExpression);
}

This didn't work and is this correct way to test it? because I'm new to Hangfire

This will not work cuz IRecurringJobManager does not have method that with that contract! That is extension method.
Underline method looks like this:
void AddOrUpdate(
    [NotNull] string recurringJobId, 
    [NotNull] Job job, 
    [NotNull] string cronExpression, 
    [NotNull] RecurringJobOptions options);

You can see it on GitHub.
So your assert would look something like this:
 // Assert
        mockRecurringJobManager.Received().AddOrUpdate(Arg.Any<string>(), Arg.Any<Job>(), Arg.Any<string>(), Arg.Any<RecurringJobOptions>());

There is a option to create a Stub Or a Fake - where you would have your own implementation of IRecurringJobManager insted of substitute:
public class RecuringJobManagerFake : IRecurringJobManager
 {
     public List<Hangfire.Common.Job> Jobs = new List<Hangfire.Common.Job>(); 
     public void AddOrUpdate([NotNull] string recurringJobId, [NotNull] Hangfire.Common.Job job, [NotNull] string cronExpression, [NotNull] RecurringJobOptions options)
     {
         Jobs.Add(job);
     }

     public void RemoveIfExists([NotNull] string recurringJobId)
     {
         throw new System.NotImplementedException();
     }

     public void Trigger([NotNull] string recurringJobId)
     {
         throw new System.NotImplementedException();
     }
 }

You can save and check everything that IRecurringJobManager recieved.
